# Ad Studio Enablement for Journey Builder - any pitfalls to avoid?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation

Working with a customer who wants to use Advertising Audiences to a Journey for those who do not open (or do click) in the email campaign.  I don't see the Ad Audiences activity listed in the client's Journey Builder and our research has led us to **[this page](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/configuring_the_add_to_active_audiences_activity/)** that says the activity is only available in accounts provisioned to use Advertising Audiences.

Assuming the client already uses Ad Studio, is seeing the AA activity merely a function of enablement? OR, if we don't see the AA activity, can we then assume that the client does not have Ad Studio?

Little help?

Answer (score 0):

If your client is using  Advertising Studio, just go ahead and log a case with marketing cloud support and it will be enabled in journey builder. If you login to marketing cloud a f navigate to Advertising Studio × Advertising Audiences , you can see how many available populations are purchased.